# Does Wix3.6 support IIS6 and IIS7 simultaneously?

Tags: iis-7, wix, iis-6, wix3.6

I intend to write a wix setup that supports IIS6 and IIS7+. Does the IIS extension of Wix3.6 support both?
That means write once, run on both? Or should I write for each server version separate code or maybe even a custom action?

thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The good news is: I wrote wix3.6 code using the default IIS extention and it works on both servers II6 and IIS7 without any special code adaptation for a specific server:-) –

Answer (score 0):

WiX [IIsExtension](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/iis_xsd_index.htm) is capable to handle any version of IIS, as far as I can tell. At least, I've successfully used it with IIS 5+. The extension contains a number of elements to create (and modify) web sites, application pools, virtual directories, and more.

The difference in code targeting various versions of IIS is that some attributes (or elements) apply to higher versions of IIS, while others are there to serve older versions. For instance, `<iis:WebAppPool>` element has no sense for pre-IIS6 versions. On the other hand, the `Isolation` attribute of the `<iis:WebApplication>` element is only valid for IIS5 and earlier.

So, if you intend to support different IIS versions, e.g 5 / 6 / 7+, you'll most likely end up having a number of `<iis:WebSite>` definitions, configured appropriately to the corresponding target IIS version.

Comment: The good news is: I wrote wix3.6 code using the default IIS extention and it works on both servers II6 and IIS7 without any special code adaptation for a specific server:-)

Comment: @Yan Sklyarenko: Perhaps you can point me to the right direction on installing the IIS 6 Virtual Dir? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21803019/create-iis-6-website-or-virtual-directory-with-wix